# Rails: Including Module based on Role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

In my app there are two `types` of Users (Athletes & Users). `Athlete` inherits the `User` class as it is using an STI setup. There are other kinds of users as well, but these kinds of users are setup based off of their roles.

Examples:

Coach --> `Regular User with the role of 'Coach'`
School Admin --> `Regular User with the role of 'School Admin'`
Contributor --> `Regular User with the role of Contributor`

Old code lingering in my app used to have `Coach` as a User Type (`class Coach < User;`), but it doesn't make a lot of sense moving forward in my app to have Coach as a single User Type. I am going to be taking the methods in the Coach model and moving them out into a module but was curious to know if there was a way to include the module only if the User had the role of Coach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. One way of doing it would be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  after_initialize :extend_with_role_module

  private

  def extend_with_role_module
    case role
    when 'coach'
      self.extend CoachModule
    when 'school_admin'
      self.extend SchoolAdminModule
    when 'contributor'
      self.extend Contributor
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

But it's terrible design as the `after_initialize` block will be called for all `User` instances that are loaded into memory. The code is probably due for a refactoring.

Source: [Ruby 2.0.0 Docs - Object#extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-extend)